# How do you estimate the energy of an impact?

Tags: stresses, energy, waves, impact

I am trying to determine the energy of elastic stress waves generated in a solid by an impact. I have a time domain waveform from a piezoelectric transducer that was placed next to the impact site, as well as the voltage/displacement calibration of the transducer.

My first idea was to integrate over the amplitude squared, but that would only give me a signal energy instead of the actual wave energy. I am not sure what impedance factor to use.

Some research has also led me towards using stress and strain tensors, but I don't understand how exactly to apply that method.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to correlate your signal to "sound energy" or use a different type of transducer such as a "force transducer".